# Mutual information between Alice and Eve in a BB84 intercept resend attack

Tags: information-theory, entropy, cryptography, bb84, mutual-information

I'm new to information theory and i need to calculate $I(A,E)$.
To calculate it I need conditional entropy $H(A|E)$.

I assume the BB84 protocol standard states $\{ |0\rangle,|1\rangle \},\{|+\rangle,|-\rangle\}$. I assume a standard intercept resend attack from Eve, that in a random fashion measures in one of the two basis and resends the measured state to Bob.

Unfortunately, when I calculate the conditional entropy, I obtain the value $\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}\log \frac{3}{4}$ and not $\frac{1}{2}$ like in Gisin original paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0101098, section VI-D.

My first calculation begun with quantum states:
i expressed conditional entropy like that
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    H(A \mid E = |0\rangle) &= - P(A = |0\rangle \mid E =|0\rangle) \log P((|0\rangle \mid E = |0\rangle)) \\
    &- P(A = |1\rangle \mid E = |0\rangle) \log P((A = |1\rangle \mid E = |0\rangle)) 
    \, .\\
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Calculating the probabilities with bayes theorem, i found this entropy to be equal to 0, and the others like that:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
H(A \mid E = |1\rangle) &= 0 \, ,\\
    H(A \mid E = |+\rangle) &= 1 \, ,\\
    H(A \mid E = |-\rangle) &= 1 \, .
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
In this way the final entropy is numerically
$$
H(A\mid E) =\frac{1}{2} \, .
$$

But then i re-thought it: perhaps i have to consider the probability not of the states, but of the bits results, because the formula i'm using is classical!
So i tried evaluating the following:
\begin{equation}
  H(A \mid E) =   P(E=0) H(A \mid E = 0)  +  P(E=1) H(A \mid E = 1) \, .
\end{equation}
but this leads me to the strange value i linked above, the same value i obtain for the conditional entropy of Alice and Bob, that is $H(A|B)$.

What am i not understanding correctly?

(If you can, give me references)

---

PS the full calculations for the first method are reported here:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    P(E = |0\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{2} \, , & \hspace{1in} P(E = |0\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) &= 0 \, ,\\
    P(E = |1\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) &= 0 \, , & P(E = |1\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{2} \, , \\
    P(E = |+\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{4} \, , & P(E = |+\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) &=\frac{1}{4}  \, ,\\
    P(E = |-\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle )  &= \frac{1}{4} \, , & P(E = |-\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{4} \, , \\
    P(A = |0\rangle) &=  \frac{1}{2} \, , & P(A = |1\rangle) &=  \frac{1}{2} \, . \\
   \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    P(E = |0\rangle) &= P(E = |0\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) P(A = |0\rangle) + 
    P(E = |0\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) P(A = |1\rangle) 
    \\ &=
    \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + 0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} \, , \\
    P(E = |1\rangle) &= P(E = |1\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) P(A = |0\rangle) + 
    P(E = |1\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) P(A = |1\rangle) 
    \\ &=
    0 \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} \, , \\
    P(E = |+\rangle) &= P(E = |+\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) P(A = |0\rangle) + 
    P(E = |+\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) P(A = |1\rangle) 
    \\ &=
    \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4} \, , \\
    P(E = |-\rangle) &=  P(E = |-\rangle \mid A = |0\rangle ) P(A = |0\rangle) + 
    P(E = |-\rangle \mid A = |1\rangle ) P(A = |1\rangle) 
    \\ &=
    \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} +  \frac{1}{4} \cdot  \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}  \, . \\
   \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
then with bayes
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    P(A= |0\rangle \mid E = |0\rangle ) &= 1 \, , & \hspace{1in} P(A= |1\rangle \mid E = |0\rangle  ) &= 0 \, ,\\
    P(A= |0\rangle \mid E = |1\rangle ) &= 0 \, , & \hspace{1in} P(A= |1\rangle \mid E = |1\rangle  ) &= 1 \, ,\\
    P(A= |0\rangle \mid E = |+\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{2} \, , & \hspace{1in} P(A= |1\rangle \mid E = |+\rangle  ) &= \frac{1}{2}\, ,\\
    P(A= |0\rangle \mid E = |-\rangle ) &= \frac{1}{2} \, , & \hspace{1in} P(A= |1\rangle \mid E = |-\rangle  ) &= \frac{1}{2} \, .
   \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
with all these numbers i have calculated the entropies reported above.

Comment: You need to add more details for this to make sense. What are the states sent, what are the measurements of Eve. It is a function of the probability distribution, you can tell us how you are calculating it.

Comment: Thanks, i tried to explain a bit more